# iOS 16 SwiftUI TextField in section header (List)

Tags: ios, list, swiftui, ios16

If run this code on `iOS16` keyboard gets dismissed randomly when character is typed (please see gif), while on `iOS15` everything is fine.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let names = ["Holly", "Josh", "Rhonda", "Ted"]
    @State var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                ForEach(searchResults, id: \.self) { name in
                    Text(name)
                }
            } header: {
                TextField("Search for name", text: $text)
            }
        }
     
    }
    
    var searchResults: [String] {
        if text.isEmpty {
            return names
        } else {
            return names.filter { $0.contains(text) }
        }
    }
}
```

It happens when content is in a section with a header. Is it bug from apple introduced in `iOS16` or am I doing something wrong? Has anyone had the same issue?

[image]

Comment: Do you experience the same on a real device?

Comment: unfortunately yes

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the way List works. I experimented a bit and if you add `.searchable` to the Section instead of the List, I am not able to reproduce the problem.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let names = ["Holly", "Josh", "Rhonda", "Ted"]
    @State var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                ForEach(searchResults, id: \.self) { name in
                    Text(name)
                }
            } header: {
                TextField("Search for name", text: $text)
            }.searchable(text: $text) // <- Here
        }
    }

    var searchResults: [String] {
        if text.isEmpty {
            return names
        } else {
            return names.filter { $0.contains(text) }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You are right, it doesn't happen in this case, but what if we assume the part of the code doesn't have `searchable` at all. This would happen anyway.

Comment: True that. It might be a bug - it seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

Searchable adds it's own textfield, you shouldn't add another one, especially not one in a section that is being removed/added.

Comment: Yeah, it was a mistake to add searchable there for this example, but if you remove searchable it will happen anyway, because the issue is somehow related to the section / header.

Comment: It’s because you’ve put a text field in a section that gets removed.

Comment: why it works on iOS15 then? So the fix would be not to use Textfield in section header? Sounds weird to me…

Comment: List changed from UITableView to UICollectionView